# PropTypes shape get marked as required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-proptypes

So I'm trying to add a shape to my components objects. The object gets loaded from the server so isn't there from the beginning. But when I add the shape to the Proptypes. It keeps throwing the error that it is marked as required but it isn't.

Does the `shape` or the `objectOf` automatically add the `isRequired` value?

```
TopicsList.propTypes = {
  topicsObject: PropTypes.shape(reportsTopicsObjectResultShape),
};
```

And the shapes:

```
export const reportsTopicObject = PropTypes.shape({
 avg_rating_ord: PropTypes.number,
 cards_with_comments: PropTypes.number,
 cards_without_comments: PropTypes.number,
 number_of_questions: PropTypes.number,
 rating_count: PropTypes.number,
 scale_version_id: PropTypes.string,
 scale_id: PropTypes.string,
 last_answered_at: PropTypes.string,
 id: PropTypes.string,
 type: PropTypes.string,
 name: PropTypes.shape(translatedObjectSystem),
 description: PropTypes.shape(translatedObjectSystem)
});

export const reportsTopicsObjectResultShape = PropTypes.shape({
 topics_distribution: PropTypes.shape({
    general: PropTypes.number,
    groups: PropTypes.number,
    people: PropTypes.number
}),
 topic_list: PropTypes.objectOf(reportsTopicObject)
});
```

I still get the error:

```
Failed prop type: The prop `topicsObject.isRequired` is marked as 
required in `TopicsList`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

It is true that is `undefined` in the beginning which is okay but I don't want it to be required.

Answer (score 8):

Neither shape nor objectOf by default cause the prop to become required. Here's an example straight from the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html):

```
// An object with property values of a certain type
  optionalObjectOf: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number),

// An object taking on a particular shape
  optionalObjectWithShape: PropTypes.shape({
    color: PropTypes.string,
    fontSize: PropTypes.number
  }),
```

Here's [an example](https://codepen.io/adam-berman/pen/bLZyXL?editors=1111) you can play around with if you want that shows using shape does not make the object required (though using .isRequired at the end will create a warning).

One thing that's worth noting is that your error message looks a little weird. Usually error messages look like this:

```
"Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `foo` is marked as required in `App`, but its value is `undefined`.
in App"
```

Where the prop is shown as `foo` not `foo.isRequired`. Yours appears to say

```
prop `topicsObject.isRequired`
```

so it might have something do with the way the shape is getting imported/exported.

Comment: Found my own mistake. I double-shaped the imported shape.
In the PropTypes I also did `PropTypes.shape(importedShape)`.
Thanks for the help anyway!